# org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, jdbc

I'm creating a maven spring mysql application and I'm facing the issue below

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No
>   suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Below is my pom-file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ec</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecWS</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
        <jersey.version>2.2</jersey.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.3</javax.servlet.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.51</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ecable" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean> 
    <bean id="LoginJDBCTemplate" class="com.ecb.dbTemplates.Validate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref ="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am using the default schema `test` created during mysqlserver creation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in your bean.xml file.

Change `value="jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test"` to `value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"`